# Gitlab python caching

Tags: gitlab-ci

This row
downloading lib
`RUN pip3 install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`
despite I have this dockerfile and job below.
Does anything wrong with this?

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl
    
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"
RUN pip3 install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5050
CMD ["python", "app_fast.py"]
```

and

```
Python dev:
  extends: .doc-build-dev
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./back/src/main/python
    IMAGE_NAME: $PY_IMAGE:$DEV_TAG
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $REGISTRY
    - pip3 install virtualenv
    - virtualenv venv
    - source venv/bin/activate
  script:
    - pip3 install -r $DOCKERFILE_PATH/requirements.txt
    - "cd $DOCKERFILE_PATH"
    - docker build --build-arg SHORT_SHA=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA 
                   --build-arg COMMIT_TIME=$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP  
                   -t $IMAGE_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
    - docker rmi -f $IMAGE_NAME
    - docker image prune -f
    - echo $IMAGE_NAME built and pushed   
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    paths:
      - .cache/pip
      - venv/     
  tags:
    - shell
```

logs I got

```
Saving cache for successful job
00:15
Creating cache master-16...
.cache/pip: found 937 matching files and directories 
venv/: found 13469 matching files and directories
```

but in next build it still download libs.